# Apply different css style file on different section tags on single page

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have 4 sections in a webpage and I want every section to use different stylesheet.
I have 4 different stylesheets, but they have the same ids and classes, but with different values. 
I need this for a demo page where I can show the different styles of the same thing in one page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS applies to the entire document, so your options are:

- Use separate documents
- Rewrite the CSS to prepend `section#your-section` (followed by a descendant combinator) to each selector.

(You could also hope and wait for [scoped CSS](http://caniuse.com/#search=scope) to be well supported).

Comment: You just beat me by 1 second :) +1